# Counting items in a List used as a Dictionary Value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

I have the following dictionary of lists working fine, but the printing at the end is borked, I can't get the counter to return correct numbers of items in each list as soon as I get more than one key in my dictionary! It's supposed to tell me how many people have chosen a particular dessert as their favourite.

```
desserts = {}

name_vote = input ('Name:vote ')

while name_vote != '':
  no_colon_name_vote = name_vote.replace(":", " ")
  listed_name_vote = no_colon_name_vote.split()
  name = listed_name_vote[0] 
  vote = ' '.join(listed_name_vote[1:])
  if vote not in desserts:
    desserts[vote] = [name]
  else:
    desserts[vote].append(name)
  name_vote = input ('Name:vote ')

for dessert in desserts:
  count = sum(len(entries) for entries in desserts.values())
  print(dessert, count,'vote(s):',' '.join(desserts[dessert]))
```

Desired output:

```
apple pie 1 vote(s): Georgina
gelato 2 vote(s): Sophia Kirsten
chocolate 3 vote(s): Greg Will James
```

But instead I get all three values set to 6!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler version which should work ok:

```
from collections import defaultdict

desserts = defaultdict(list)

while True:
    name_vote = input('Name:vote ')
    if name_vote == '':
        break
    name, vote = name_vote.split(':')
    desserts[vote].append(name)

for dessert, names in desserts.items():
    print(dessert, len(names), 'vote(s):', ' '.join(names))
```

Note the simpler string splitting code, and also how doing the while loop [like this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) means you can avoid having to repeat the line of setup code. Also, using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and iterating over the dict `items()` also simplify the code a bit

Comment: Much appreciated! I'm beginning to see that my logic is sound, but I've got to become better at making my code more efficient! Early days!!

Comment: I'm assuming that defaultdict is a way of 'scaffolding' your code, so that a blank dictionary of the right format (in this case with the value as a list) is ready and waiting to be populated with as little obstruction as possible?

Comment: yes it's a shortcut, if you try to access a key that hasn't been added yet it will create one for you using the provided 'default function'... in our case the `list` constructor. so you can skip the 'if key exists' checking and just treat it as if there's always a list ready for you

Comment: Much appreciated. Again!

Answer (score 0):

`count` is based on the `sum` over the entire `desserts` list, not `desserts[dessert]`.

Try this:

```
count = len(desserts[dessert])
```

Also consider using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

---

Let's take a step back and try this instead:

```
desserts = collections.defaultdict(list)
while name_vote != '':
    name_vote = input('Name:vote ')
    if not name_vote:
        break
    name, vote = no_colon_name_vote.split(':')
    desserts[vote].append(name)

for dessert in desserts:
    count = len(desserts[dessert])
    print(dessert, count,'vote(s):',' '.join(desserts[dessert]))
```

Comment: Tried it and it's returning the total number of characters in the names as opposed to the number of names in each list. But at least they're not all the same value! Unfamiliar with default.dic as well. Tutorials I'm working through not covered it yet but I'll do some research.